# How can I get the last received branch in a bare git repo?

Tags: git

I have a bare repo setup on a staging server. I pull from there, develop, and then push back to the remote repo, and I have a post-receive hook setup to checkout the repo to the staging servers DocumentRoot with `git --work-tree=/server/document/root --git-dir=/path/to/repo checkout -f`. That always checksout the master branch, however. Ideally, I'd like to be able to have that hook checkout the last received branch, or most recently updated branch, because I'd prefer not to merge with master until I'm happy with my changes and they've been inspected on the staging server. Is this possible, and if so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a problem here because the notion of "last received" or "last updated" is not well defined.

Let's assume that this repo is updated via `push` (probably a safe assumption).  Now suppose two different `push`-ers start `git push` at approximately the same time, one at 10:01 AM and one at 10:02 AM.  Person A, starting at 10:01, pushes an update to branches `A1` and `A2` (both are included in a single push).  Person B, starting at 10:02, pushes an update to branch `B` (only—a more typical single-branch push).

Person A, however, is on a slow network and it takes severl minutes for his upload to actually make it over and for his proposal to update branches `A1` and `A2` to finish, so on the *receiving* side this occurs at 10:03 AM.  Person B is on a fast network and his push-proposal is started and finished at 10:02.

Your repo scripts check the proposals out and decide they are allowed, so branch `B` is updated at 10:02.  You'll therefore deploy branch `B`, which is easy enough.

Then person A's push finally makes it through and branches `A1` and `A2` are updated simultaneously at 10:03.  Which branch do you deploy now?

Furthermore, does it matter that person B's push command was initiated later than person A's?

---

Once you figure out the answer to this question, actually deploying a particular branch is easy enough: just have your hook check out that particular branch, rather than allowing the repo to just use the `HEAD` branch (which is generally `master`: a bare repo still has a `HEAD` and it's normally just never touched).  (Note that git will attempt to optimize the checkout process via the index.  Depending on many other things, you may want to tweak or defeat this.  Note also that checking out a particular named branch will change `HEAD`, unless you use the syntax that avoids changing `HEAD`.)

### OK, so, how?

#### In a hook of course, but let's run through the hooks

There are three hooks that are run on the server when a client does a push:

- pre-receive
- update
- post-receive

Each of these has somewhat different purposes, though practically speaking only two are *necessary*.  First, the client uploads everything (all commits and any tree and blob objects needed).  Then:

1. git invokes the `pre-receive` hook, feeding it a series of lines on stdin.  Each line has two SHA-1 values (current aka "old", and proposed replacement or "new") and a ref-name.  Either, but not both, of the old and new SHA-1 values can be all-zeros, indicating that the ref is being created (did not exist before) or deleted (will not exist if the push is allowed).  The pre-receive hook should read all the lines, check each ref-name and each supplied SHA-1, and decide whether the push, in its entirety, is to be accepted or rejected.

   Note that ref-names are always fully qualified: a branch like `dev/joe` is `refs/heads/dev/joe`; a tag like `v1.2` is `refs/tags/v1.2`; and so on.

   If the pre-receive hook rejects the push, the client is informed that the push is entirely rejected, and the whole thing stops at this point.  (To reject, simply exit with a nonzero status; to accept, exit with a zero status.)
2. git invokes the `update` hook, one invocation per ref-name that is to be updated, passing it the ref-name, the old SHA-1, and the new SHA-1.  The update hook should decide whether this particular change is to be accepted or rejected.

   If the update hook rejects the change, the client is informed that the one reference-update was rejected, but the push goes on to try the remaining changes.
3. Now that all refs have been individually updated or rejected, git runs the `post-receive` hook.  This hook gets the same input (on stdin) as the pre-receive hook.

   Because all updates are done, this hook is generally a good place to deploy a new version.

   Note that the post-receive hook cannot stop any updating, but due to a small bug in git, if it exits nonzero, the client is informed that the push failed (at least with some versions of git), so it should exit zero to avoid astonishment.

#### So which hook records and which hook deploys?

This part is up to you.  The post-receive hook is usually the right place but you can do this wherever you like.

If you choose to do a deployment in the post-receive hook, but make a decision in an earlier hook, you'll need to record the decision.  Where you record it is up to you.  If you do the deployment in the same place you choose what to deploy, you don't *have* to record the decision, because the same bit of code is doing both things so it can just remember.

As for how to achieve the deployment, one really simple method is to remove the target work-tree and then do a `git checkout` using the form that overwrites the work-tree with files from a particular commit.  Let's say that branch `refs/heads/B` was updated to commit `1234567`.  Then:

```
rm -rf /server/document/root && 
  mkdir /server/document/root &&
  git --work-tree=/server/document/root checkout -f B -- .
```

will do the trick, without altering what `HEAD` is in the bare repository.

If you want to have git alter `HEAD`, and want to allow git's index to track what's going on, it's much easier:

```
git --work-tree=/server/document/root checkout -f B
```

In this case `HEAD` will record the branch most recently checked-out.  This also affects new clones of the bare repository, which is one reason why you might want it, or might not want it.

How do you decide what branch to deploy?  You'll need to write some code, but consider the following shell fragment:

```
while read oldsha newsha ref; do
    case "$ref" in
    refs/heads/*)
        branch=${ref#refs/heads/}
        reftype=branch;;
    *)
        reftype=unknown;;
    esac
done
```

Also remember that you'll need to check whether the reference is being deleted (`$newsha` is 40 `0`s) since you can't check out a branch that no longer exists.

There are a whole lot of deployment scripts Out There, of varying quality.  Grab a few, poke through them, and keep the above notes in mind.

Comment: Very good points. I guess I'd prefer to deploy the branch that was received last on the servers side, regardless of when they were pushed (so 2 branches are pushed at the same time, one fast network one slow network, slow network would be the one deployed when both are completed). If that makes sense.... in practice however, I'm not really concerned since, at least for now, there will be only one person responsible for pushing to the staging server. I hope that makes sense, I'm a bit of a git newb.

Comment: Yes, it's just something to consider when doing these.  Personally I think it's better to have two or more deployment areas, one for testing and one for production: pushes to `master`, for instance, would always deploy to production and pushes to any branch whose name starts with `sandbox` or `develop` or whatever would go the testing area(s).

Comment: So, I'm taking it that what I want to do is possible... now I'm just lacking the "how". I do plan to eventually get to a deployment strategy like you suggest, I'd need to have it working on staging before I can make my case. Can you explain how I'd change that hook to checkout the most recently updated branch?

Comment: Added a big edit describing mechanism.  You'll still need to decide on policy yourself, and write more code (or get it from elsewhere).

Comment: Ya, great addition - great answer! Definitely helped me understand what's going on more deeply. Thank you.